# В docker-compose нужно запустить один контейнер после другого

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Для этого в поле command вместо дефолтной стартовой команды вызываю скрипт .sh. Внутри в цикле хочу пинговать mongodb, и как только база окажется поднятой, я сразу запускаю стартовую команду для контейнера(мой сервис который находится в контейнере накатывает миграции, поэтому до старта контейнера я должен быть уверен что база поднята и существует). Но цикл превращается в бесконечный. Вот пример моего кода:

```
#!/bin/sh

host="127.0.0.1"
port="27017"
# дефолтные команды старта контейнера
cmd="yarn migrate && yarn dev"

echo "Start"

until `nc -z -v -w5 "$host" "$port"`; do
  echo Sleep
done

echo "Completed"

exec $cmd
```

Comment: для ожидания лучше использовать что-нибудь типа [docker-compose-wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но выбрали другой вариант и пошли по нему